# supplied cron.yaml not reflected in admin console cron page

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron, yaml

I added a basic cron.yaml file to a GAE project and updated the project. Its the default version. I didn't get any parsing errors during upload but there is no entry in the cron tasks on the GAE dashboard to indicate the yaml file was understood

Anyone familiar with drupal will understand the structure of the cron url, it appends a unique key to the request to stop your site getting bombed with requests to cron

Could the length of the url be the problem?
The admin logs on GAE don't show that a cron job was added

here is my cron.yaml (except for some #comments)

```
- description: Drupal system cron
  url: /cron.php?cron_key=Rand0-CharactersAndNUmbersInDifferentCases2
  schedule: every 60 mins
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your yaml file start with cron:?

```
cron:
 - description: Drupal system cron
   url: /cron.php?cron_key=Rand0-CharactersAndNUmbersInDifferentCases2
   schedule: every 60 mins
```

The syntax is correct, so problem must lie in uploading of the file. Do the tasks show in the local admin panel (usually located at `http://localhost:8000/cron`)? Perhaps try re-uploading the cron file with `appcfg.py update_cron`

Aside, it's not necessary to protect the task using a unique key - in your app.yaml you can specify login: admin, as shown:

`- url: /cron.*
   script: cron.php
   login: admin`

Scheduled tasks run with admin privileges: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/cron#PHP_app_yaml_Securing_URLs_for_cron

Comment: Drupal needs a scheduled cron job to execute in order to work properly so it wouldn't be useful to restrict it to admins

Comment: I'm not sure which steps solved it but I ran appcfg.py update_cron "project" as you suggested and that created the cron entry on the dashboard. I think it could have been because my project path when updating the whole project pointed to the app.yaml file. Changing it to appcfg.py --oauth2 update "PathtoProjectFolder" instead of  "PathtoProjectFolder\app.yaml" updates the cron entry and also outputs cron details in the command output along with deployment successful, checking if update app version is serving

Comment: Also forgot to mention I did start with cron: I just forgot to include it here